# Representation of the Orthogonal Projection

Tags: orthogonality, pseudoinverse

We want to show that orthogonal projection can be written as
\begin{align}
C\cdot C^+=\left(I_N-\frac{1}{N}\iota\iota'\right),
\end{align}
where $C=\left(\omega\iota'-I_N\right)$, $I_N$ is the identity matrix of dimension $N$, $\omega$ is an $N\times1$ vector, $\iota'\omega=1$ and $C^+$ denotes the Moore–Penrose pseudo-inverse of $C$. Numerically, we know that this holds for any vector $\omega$ fulfilling the summing-up-constraint.

Here, $C$ is a linear operator from $\mathbb{R}^{T\times N}$ onto $\mathbb{R}^{T\times N}$ and we want to show that despite of the choice of $\omega$, the orthogonal projector $CC^+$ is always of the same form.

Comment: Orthogonal projection onto what subspace? What is the summing-up constraint?

Comment: The summing-up-constraint is just $\iota'\omega=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We find finally that $C^+$ has the following form:
\begin{align}
C^{+}= w \iota' - I  \frac{1}{\omega'\omega} \omega \omega' - \left(  \frac{1}{N} \frac{1}{\omega'\omega} + 1\right) \omega \iota' + \frac{1}{N} \iota \iota'
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean $C$ is a linear operator from $\mathbb{R}^{T\times N}$ onto $\mathbb{R}^{T\times N}$, mapping an element $x\in\mathbb{R}^{T\times N}\mapsto xC=x\omega\iota'-x$ and you want to show that despite of the choice of $\omega$ the orthogonal projector $CC^+$ is always of the same form?

Idempotence of $\left(I_N−\frac{1}{N}\iota_N\iota_N ′\right)$ is easy to show, therefore this term defines a projection on $\mathbb{R}^{T\times N}$. However, I do not know how to proove the orthogonality.
First, as $CC^+$ is the orthogonal projection onto the range of $C$ it is necessary to show that range$(C)$ does not depend on $\omega$. In a second step it should be sufficient to show that $CC^+$ is a self-adjoint operator.

Another way would be to check if setting $C^+C=\left(I_N−\frac{1}{N}\iota_N\iota_N ′\right)$ fulfills the properties of the Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse:
\begin{align}
CC^+C=&C\\
C^+CC^+=&C^+\\
(CC^+)'=&CC^+\\
(C^+C)'=&C^+C
\end{align}
The first and third equations hold, but I have trouble with the second and fourth:
$C^+CC^+=C^+$ requires $C^+ \iota_N =0$ but as I do not have a closed form solution for $C^+$ I cannot confirm that this holds.

EDIT: [The answer to **this question**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287611/conditional-inverse-find-set-of-solutions-for-axa-a-a-left1-n-alpha-iota) gives you that $C^+$ is an element of the set: $$S=\{C+\omega y^T+\iota c^T:\;y,z\in\mathbb{R}^N\}.$$ 
Plug-in such an element and find $z$ such that $(CC^+)'=CC^+$ gives you 
$$z=\omega(\iota'z-1)+\frac{1}{N}\iota$$ 
The choice of $y$ is irrelevant for the representation of $CC^+$ as $\omega y'$ is in the nullspace of $C$. For one $z$ in the form given above you'll find $$C(C+\omega y'+z \iota')=I_N-\frac{1}{N}\iota \iota'.$$

Comment: Yes, $C$ is a linear operator from $\mathbb{R}^{T\times N}$ onto $\mathbb{R}^{T\times N}$ and we want to show that despite of the choice of $\omega$, the orthogonal projector $CC^+$ is always of the same form.